# Targeting multiple countries with one locale

Tags: craft-features

I'm new to Craft.  I've the following questions about locales for a international company.

Configuration could look like this:

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'domain.com/en',
    'en_us' => 'domain.com/us'
    'it' => 'domain.com/it',
    'de' => 'domain.com/de',
    'es_es' => 'domain.com/es',
    'es' => 'domain.com/es'
)
```

1. I want to have a generic international version, without any slug, in English. How am I supposed to configure that?
2. I want the same contents for Spain and other Latin countries but I want to distinguish locales, to target at least Spain specifically. Do I need to create a locale or just use the correct `hreflang` in HTML?

Comment: For #1, wouldn't the generic English version just be `'en' => 'domain.com'`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did in the end. I wasn't sure it was the proper way.